# ionic 3 print plugin is not working

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am using ionic 3 and https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer/

```
    let options: PrintOptions = {
            name: 'MyPrint',
            duplex: false,
            landscape: false,
            grayscale: true
    };

    this.printer.print("CONTENT", options);
```

this is how i am trying to get and print popup.but it is not functioning. and console the following log.

Error: exec proxy not found for :: Printer :: print

The app compiles, installes without error..just print is not working.

Comment: Are you trying it in your browser?

Comment: Browser but via plateform i mean via corodva run browser. Because i am unable to get what is going wrong on actual device as there is nothing to see for live log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, By moving whole project files (pages, js, ts files) into new blank project solved my problem. I think problem was in node_module or something apart from my actual files.